# can't initialize an adapter from a callback method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter

Im trying to initialize my adapter from a callback method that is in another class, however, its not working, there are no logs or crashes. If I check the size of the adapter within that method, it shows the actual size but else where,it seems to be empty. 
Here is my setup

**The Adapter**

```
public class SlidesAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
ArrayList<String> pictureUrls = new ArrayList<>();
private String type;
private Context ctx;

    public SlidesAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> pictureUrls, String type, Context ctx) {
        super(fm);
        this.pictureUrls = pictureUrls;
        this.type = type;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return SlidesFragment.newInstance(pictureUrls.get(position), type);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pictureUrls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return RedditClient.getInstance().getPageTitle(position);
    }
}
```

**My callback method**
If I check the size of the adapter from this method, I get the actual size, but if I check from another place, e.g from within the adapter itself, its empty.

```
    @Override
public void updateCollectionData( ArrayList<CollectionModel> collectionModelArrayList) {
    this.collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(collectionModelArrayList.get(0).getCollectionName());
    ArrayList<String> unsplashLinks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (CollectionModel model : collectionModelArrayList){
        unsplashLinks.add(String.valueOf(model.getCollectionID()));
    }
    Toaster.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(unsplashLinks.size()), Toaster.LENGTH_SHORT, Toaster.INFO).show();
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SlidesAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), unsplashLinks, Contract.UNSPLASH_TYPE, getApplicationContext());
    mProgressBar.hide();
}
```

This method here provides data to my callback method:

```
    public void getCollections(MainActivity mainActivity){

    this.callBacks = mainActivity;

    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance().initialize(Contract.UNSPLASH_BASE_URL);
    UnsplashApi service = retrofit.create(UnsplashApi.class);
    Call<List<UnsplashPojo>> call = service.getFeaturedCollectionList(Contract.UNSPLASH_APP_ID);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UnsplashPojo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<UnsplashPojo>> call, Response<List<UnsplashPojo>> response) {
            CollectionModel collectionModel;

            for (UnsplashPojo unsplashPojo : response.body()){
                collectionModel = new CollectionModel(unsplashPojo.title, unsplashPojo.id);
                collectionModelArrayList.add(collectionModel);
            }
            callBacks.updateCollectionData(collectionModelArrayList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<UnsplashPojo>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here.

```
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return RedditClient.getInstance().getPageTitle(position);
    }
```

this line   `RedditClient.getInstance().getPageTitle(position);` is excuting in another thread other than the thread in which your adapter is initialized.

Suggestion for testing :
add fake titles list. If it works. then initialize your adapter and the title list just after you get all data needed by the adapter.